# How to link a sub-domain to external domain

Tags: mapping, dns, cname

Say i had a site with a few clients on it...

```
http://www.example.com/client1/
http://www.example.com/client2/
http://www.example.com/client3/
```

and i wanted them to be displayed at the following domains...

```
http://www.example.com/client1/ > http://www.client1.co.uk/
http://www.example.com/client2/ > http://www.client2.co.uk/
http://www.example.com/client3/ > http://www.client3.co.uk/
```

How would i do this with DNS, Would i use CNAME?

I want all the links to work still so this would work...

```
http://www.example.com/client1/images/pic.jpg to
http://www.client1.co.uk/images/pic.jpg
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using the DNS. A DNS system does not know anything about HTTP or websites; it just knows how to translate a hostname like www.example.com to an IP address, that's it.

If you use Apache just use this in the .htaccess file

```
Redirect /client1/ http://www.client1.co.uk/
```

More details at [the Apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html)